# Is there any fix for the controller of Saints Row 2 on PC

Tags: controllers, saints-row-2

I recently bought Saints Row 2 at Steam, however, the controls seem to be unnatural and hard to control the main character.

Things like strafing left or rotating the character are unbeliveably ugly. It's different from what GTA4 did.

It looks like the port from the consoles wasn't done right or I'm missing something.

Are there any hotfixes for this or recommended settings?

Comment: It isn't just the controls that were poorly ported. The performance is so poor that there's actually [a community that is set on fixing it](http://saintsrowpowertools.com/). They even have a calculator that shows you what your performance gain is.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered getting a gamepad for PC?  Unfortunately, developers seem to be spending less and less effort on good controls for PC ports of console games.  I recently got so fed up with this that I just gave in and bought a USB controller (Assassin's Creed PC controls pushed me over the edge).

I'd recommend an xbox controller (or one of the many cheaper, driver-compatible third-party controllers).

Comment: I'm probably going to try that, since the controls don't seem to be well tuned for keyboard+mouse.

Comment: I have tried (and tried!) to get comfortable using my Xbox controller in Saints Row 2 for PC. I've played for weeks, and I *still* can't get used to the buttons. `X` for accelerating a car? `RB` for sprinting? Constantly having to pan the camera using the right stick is insanely confusing, and because of all this I find myself playing like a novice. I tried remapping some keys, but I soon discovered that although the triggers may be sensible for driving, they double-map to shooting out of the car at the same time. I'm afraid to say that the incredibly poor controls completely ruined this game.